# Problem in FPDF header with a php variable

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a php file that I use to print pdf (using FPDF). In this file I have a variable $date and I would like to show this variable $date in the header on each of the pages of my pdf document.
That is my variable $date:

```
$convert_date=strtotime($selected_date);
global $date;
$date=date("d/m/Y",$convert_date);
```

And this is the class FPDF:

```
class PDF extends FPDF{

    function setDate($dat){
        $this->header_date = $dat;
    }

    function getDate(){
        return $this->header_date;
    }

    function Header(){
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
        $this->setDate($date);
        $this->Write (10, '       Date: '); //1° Write
        $this->Write (10, $this->getDate()); //2° Write NOT WORKING 
        $this->Ln();
    } ...
```

The problem is that the second $this->Write prints nothing.

I checked that if I call **$this->setDate('abcd');**, it prints "abcd" ok.

**How can I pass this $date variable in my pdf header function?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure because I've not used them in about five years, but don't you have to declare $date as being a global inside the `Header()` function?

```
function Header() {
    $date = $GLOBALS['date'];
    ...
```